# How to solve this nonlinear constrained optimization efficiently?

Tags: optimization, nonlinear-optimization, non-convex-optimization

Set $\{\alpha_i\}$ and $\{\beta_i\}$ as the variables, the optimization problem I need to solve is as follows:
\begin{equation}
    \begin{split}
     \min\max_{i}\quad &\frac{(a_i^2+b_i^2+c_i^2+d_i^2)^2}{(a_id_i-b_ic_i)^2}
    \end{split}
\end{equation}
where \begin{equation}
    \begin{split}
    a_i = \sum_{j=1}^{M}l_{ij}\alpha_i,\quad b_i = \sum_{j=1}^{M}h_{ij}\alpha_i,\quad c_i = \sum_{j=1}^{M}l_{ij}\beta_i\quad d_i = \sum_{j=1}^{M}h_{ij}\beta_i
    \end{split}
\end{equation}
$\{l_{ij}\}$ and $\{h_{ij}\}$ are the given coefficients.
By introducing the auxiliary variable t, we can solve the following equivalent problem:
\begin{equation}
    \begin{split}
     \min\quad &t\\
     \mathrm{s.t.} \quad &(a_i^2+b_i^2+c_i^2+d_i^2)^2-t(a_id_i-b_ic_i)^2\leq 0,\quad i=1,2,\cdots,N
    \end{split}
\end{equation}

I try to solve this problem using the function "fmincon" in MATLAB and select the "active-set" algorithm. But it takes a long time for each iteration and the Max constraint is not zero. I don't know why? Is there any other software to solve this problem?[image]

Comment: I have no proposal. Just curious where such a problem appears.

Comment: Do you have any reason to believe this problem is convex? It does not seem so to me (not even quasiconvex).